# Huge \not and Feynman \slashed for bigger equations or symbols

Tags: symbols, amsmath, math-operators

We can write

```
$\not{a}$ 

$\slashed{a}$
```

under

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

for the following symbol:

[image]

[image]

What if I have a larger equation like:

```
$
\int a b c d e f g dx
$
```

How do we write a bigger `\not` for it? And bigger `\slashed`?

[image]

```
$
\not{\int a b c d e f g dx}
$
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, I would add that `\not a` is not proper usage.  The `\not` macro expects to work on an object of category `\mathrel`, such as `\not=`.  For use with other categories, you should wrap them in a `\mathrel`, such as `\not\mathrel{B}`, or more precisely, `A\mathord{\not\mathrel{B}}C`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for the `cancel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
$
\cancel{\int a b c d e f g dx}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]